# Uncertain about what the function does: syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, react-final-form

```
export const composeValidators = (...validators) => value => validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);
```

I am uncertain of the syntax of the above code. Can some one break it down for me?

I am new to arrow functions but I see multiple in here!!! The function gets called on a redux-final-form validator field. How do I change it so that it returns a undefined for no validation failure and '! validation message' for a validation failure.

I wonder if it is possible to be able to make a **newComposeValidators** function that passes the same parameters to the composeValidators function and returns the error message prepended with the exclamation point and space?

it gets used as following:

```
Field name="postalCode" validate={composeValidators(requiredValidator, postalCodeValidator)}>
                  {({ input, meta }) => (
                    <Fragment>
                      <StyledInput
                        validationFailed={meta.touched && meta.error}
                        placeholder={postalCodePlaceholder}
                        required
                        {...input}
                      />
                      <StyledFieldError meta={meta} />
                    </Fragment>
                  )}
                </Field>
```

validators are defined as:

```
  const messages = {
  required: 'Input is required',
  email: 'Invalid Email',
  phone: 'Invalid Phone Number',
  postalCode: 'Invalid Postal Code',
  positiveNumber: 'Must be greater than 0',
  pastDate: 'Please enter a valid date in the past',
};

const requiredValidator = (value) => (value && value.trim().length ? undefined : messages.required);
const emailValidator = (value) => (!value || emailRegex.test(value) ? undefined : messages.email);
const phoneValidator = (value) => (!value || phoneNumberRegex.test(value) ? undefined : messages.phone);
const postalCodeValidator = (value) =>
  !value || zipCodeRegex.test(value) || canadianPostalCodeRegex.test(value) ? undefined : messages.postalCode;
const positiveNumberValidator = (value) =>
  value && Number.isInteger(+value) && +value > 0 ? undefined : messages.positiveNumber;
const pastDateValidator = (value) => {
  if (!value || !dateRegex.test(value)) {
    return messages.pastDate;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const composeValidators = (...validators) => value => validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined)
```

This function take an array of validator functions as parameter and return another function.

The returned function take your value as parameter then map through validator functions,
if validator(value) return value then error is assigned to that value and so on (undefined is initialvalue of for error), then return error

take a look at [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) function

your function might looks like below

```
export const composeValidators = (...validators) => {
  return function checkError(value){
    // validators = [ requiredValidator, postalCodeValidator ] in this case    
    // imaginevalidators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined) does something like this
    let error = undefined
    validators.map(validator => { // loop through array of validator function
      if(validator(value)) {
        error = validator(value)
      }
    })
    return error
  }
}
```

append ! and a space to error if validate fails

```
validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || `! ${validator(value)}`, undefined)
```

Comment: I am confused. Where are we getting or passing this error from?

Comment: It's actually getting a flexible list of arguments, which are validator functions, that are transformed into an array. Your answer is misleading

Comment: @iMoses yeah, just try to let him know validators is an array in this case

Comment: I am a new js programmer and syntax gets my head spinning sometimes. couple of questions: I understand validators is an array as I may pass in multiple arguments but 'value'? which one? where? what? error?? what the hell is that? Can some one explain me in detail? Sorry for being so blunt.

Comment: I understand the reduce function too. But what is 'error'? I never passed it? from where is it coming from?

Comment: @Ackman error is create by reduce(undefined is initialvalue)
reduce will map loop though validator function, if validator(value) return value, error is assigned to this value, end of the loop reduce return that error

Comment: Thank you! also can we change that to something like if validator(value)!==undefined return `! ${error}` else return undefined?

Comment: I am trying to append ! and a space to string if validation fails

Comment: Thank you so much :) I appreciate the help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to explain this is through an example. So given this function:

```
export const composeValidators = (...validators) => value => validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined)
```

We can call it as follows:

```
composeValidators(valiadationRuleFunction1, valiadationRuleFunction2)( 'someValueHere')
```

so `(...validators)` becomes `[valiadationRuleFunction1, valiadationRuleFunction2]` and `'someValueHere'` becomes `value`.

---

In terms of

```
validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined)
```

we start off by defining 'error' as an undefined value. The first time this runs, the error will be undefined therefore it will call `valiadationRuleFunction1` with the value supplied i.e. `valiadationRuleFunction1('someValueHere')`.

If this passes validation, 'error' will still be undefined and therefore `valiadationRuleFunction2` will then be called with the same value supplied i.e. `valiadationRuleFunction2('someValueHere')`.

The current function does short circuit if it encounters an error, i.e. if `valiadationRuleFunction1('someValueHere')` was to return a validation error - then 'error' will now be defined.
When we do this check `error || validator(value)` - the error will be returned and `valiadationRuleFunction2('someValueHere)` will not be executed.

This works well for single error messages being displayed based on priority i.e. the most important validation rules should be passed into 'composeValidators' first.
If there is a scenario where you need to display multiple error messages, we would change the default 'error' value in the reduce function from 'undefined' to an '[]'. Each time a validator runs and returns an error - we would push this error to the array and return an array of errors.

---

**Testing this function that returns a function**

Given we have a validator (this will return an error when a value isn't specified i.e. required validation):

```
export const valiadationRuleFunction1 = value => !value ? 'Please provide a value' : undefined`
```

1. Import this rule using the * syntax i.e. `import * as ValidationRules from './pathToWhereThisRuleLives'`
2. Create a spy for this validation rule e.g. `const valiadationRuleFunction1Spy = jest.spyOn(Validation,'valiadationRuleFunction1');`
3. Call the 'composeValidators' function with the validator and a value that will trigger an error and assert the error message returned i.e. `expect(composeValidators(valiadationRuleFunction1)('')).toBe('Please provide a value')`;
4. We can then use the `valiadationRuleFunction1Spy` to assert that the actual validation function was called i.e. `expect(valiadationRuleFunction1Spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`.